# Split an array composed by twisted arrays

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, performance

I have a sensor that send to me a 1-dimensional float array that I have to split in 4 different subarrays. My array represents a Frame, that is composed by 1024 Ramps. Each Ramp has header and data of 4 channels (the data I want to split). Each channel has 2 floats, one for the real part and one for the complex part. To clarified this, I have attached an image with the structure:

[image]

I need to unravel this big array in 4 arrays with only data, each one for a single channel. This must be done fast. My implementation takes around 850ms, but sadly this is not fast enough. So far I have written the next code:

```
IntPtr ptr = (IntPtr)frameInfo.ptr; // The pointer to the buffer

for (int i = 0; i < nChannels; i++)
{
    channelFrames[i].data = new float[nRamps * nPoints * 2];
}

 for (int ramp = 0; ramp < nRamps; ramp++)
 {
     ptr += (int)rawHeaderSize; // Skip the header

     for (int point = 0; point < nPoints; point++)
     {
          for (int channel = 0; channel < nChannels; channel++)
          {
               Marshal.Copy(ptr, channelFrames[channel].data, (int)(point *2 + ramp*nPoints*2), 2);

               ptr += (sizeof(float) * 2); // Move to the next data                          
          }
     }
}
```

Any ideas on how to do this faster?

Comment: Maybe you should try [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Your diagram doesn't seem to match your description or code? "Each channel has 2 floats" but your diagram shows 8 floats per channel? What is point and what is nPoints? And why are you copying 2 floats at a time (that would be re0+re1 then re2+re3 according to your diagram)? I assume `data` is a `float` `Array` since you assign a `new float[]` to it.

Comment: @NetMage No, it shows 2 floats per channel. Each float is 4 bytes so Re0Re1Re2Re3 makes a float and Im0Im1Im2Im3 makes another float. nPoints is 4096. The Marshal.Copy already changes 4 bytes to a float. I need to copy both floats, the real part and the imaginary part to the channel array.

Comment: I understand - each one represents a byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Marshal.Copy()` is likely to be performance bottleneck, since it calls into unmanaged code and this call is too expensive to copy just 2 floats. Following uses unsafe code (must be enabled in project properties and method must be decorated with `unsafe` modifier) to avoid using `Marshal.Copy()` and copies data manually. Also inner loop (that iterates over channels) is unrolled, for some additional performance gain (drawback of this is that code is hardcoded for 4 channels).

My measurements shows nearly 10x performance boost over original method.

```
//Pin arrays with channel data in memory and get pointers of these fixed arrays
fixed (float* fixed_ch0ptr = channelFrames[0].data)
fixed (float* fixed_ch1ptr = channelFrames[1].data)
fixed (float* fixed_ch2ptr = channelFrames[2].data)
fixed (float* fixed_ch3ptr = channelFrames[3].data)
{
    //fixed arrays pointer cannot be modified, we must create writable copies ot these pointers
    float* ch0ptr = fixed_ch0ptr;
    float* ch1ptr = fixed_ch1ptr;
    float* ch2ptr = fixed_ch2ptr;
    float* ch3ptr = fixed_ch3ptr;

    //unsafe pointer to array from sensor
    float* floatptr = (float*)ptr;

    for (int ramp = 0; ramp < nRamps; ramp++)
    {
        floatptr = (float*)((byte*)(floatptr) + (int)rawHeaderSize); // Skip the header

        for (int point = 0; point < nPoints; point++)
        {
            //Unrolling loop that iterates over channelFrames can give as some additional performance gains

            //copy channel 0 data
            *ch0ptr++ = *(floatptr++);
            *ch0ptr++ = *(floatptr++);

            //copy channel 1 data
            *ch1ptr++ = *(floatptr++);
            *ch1ptr++ = *(floatptr++);

            //copy channel 2 data
            *ch2ptr++ = *(floatptr++);
            *ch2ptr++ = *(floatptr++);

            //copy channel 3 data
            *ch3ptr++ = *(floatptr++);
            *ch3ptr++ = *(floatptr++);
        }
    }
}
```